# No Windows SDK found when installing SpiderMonkey

Tags: windows, firefox, installation, visual-c++

I'm following [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites) to install SpiderMokey.

I've downloaded and installed Visual Studio Community 2015, then restarted.
I've downloaded and installed MozillaBuild package.

When I go to `c:\mozilla-build` and run `start-shell-msvc2015.bat`, it says

```
MozillaBuild Install Directory: C:\mozilla-build\
Visual C++ 2015 Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\

No Windows SDK found. Exiting.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'd expect it to find the Windows SDK, which I assume I just downloaded with VS 2015, but it isn't.

What is it looking for and how can I get it?

### EDIT2:

After installing the Windows SDK 8.1 and trying again, I get this error:

```
Unable to call a suitable vcvars script. Exiting.
```

Here's the entire install script:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Reset some env vars and set some others.
SET CYGWIN=
SET INCLUDE=
SET LIB=
IF NOT DEFINED MOZ_NO_RESET_PATH (
  SET PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
)

REM mintty is available as an alternate terminal, but is not enabled by default due
REM to various usability regressions. Set USE_MINTTY to 1 to enable it.
IF NOT DEFINED USE_MINTTY (
  SET USE_MINTTY=
)

SET ERROR=
SET MOZILLABUILD=%~dp0
SET TOOLCHAIN=

REM Figure out if we're on a 32-bit or 64-bit host OS.
REM NOTE: Use IF ERRORLEVEL X to check if the last ERRORLEVEL was GEQ(greater or equal than) X.
SET WINCURVERKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
REG QUERY "%WINCURVERKEY%" /v "ProgramFilesDir (x86)" >nul 2>nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET WIN64=1
) ELSE (
  REM Bail early if the x64 MSVC start script is invoked on a 32-bit host OS.
  REM Note: We explicitly aren't supporting x86->x64 cross-compiles.
  IF "%MOZ_MSVCBITS%" == "64" (
    SET ERROR=The MSVC 64-bit toolchain is not supported on a 32-bit host OS. Exiting.
    GOTO _QUIT
  )
  SET WIN64=0
)

REM Append moztools to PATH
IF "%WIN64%" == "1" (
  SET MOZ_TOOLS=%MOZILLABUILD%moztools-x64
) ELSE (
  SET MOZ_TOOLS=%MOZILLABUILD%moztools
)
SET PATH=%PATH%;%MOZ_TOOLS%\bin

REM Set up the MSVC environment if called from one of the start-shell-msvc batch files.
IF DEFINED MOZ_MSVCVERSION (
  IF NOT DEFINED VCDIR (
    REM Set the MSVC registry key.
    IF "%WIN64%" == "1" (
      SET MSVCKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\%MOZ_MSVCVERSION%.0\Setup\VC
    ) ELSE (
      SET MSVCKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\%MOZ_MSVCVERSION%.0\Setup\VC
    )

    REM Find the MSVC installation directory and bail if none is found.
    REG QUERY !MSVCKEY! /v ProductDir >nul 2>nul
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      SET ERROR=Microsoft Visual C++ %MOZ_MSVCYEAR% was not found. Exiting.
      GOTO _QUIT
    )
    FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY !MSVCKEY! /v ProductDir') DO SET VCDIR=%%B
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED SDKDIR (
    REM Set the Windows SDK registry keys.
    SET SDKPRODUCTKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Products
    SET SDKROOTKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots
    IF "%WIN64%" == "1" (
      SET WIN81SDKKEY={5247E16E-BCF8-95AB-1653-B3F8FBF8B3F1}
    ) ELSE (
      SET WIN81SDKKEY={A1CB8286-CFB3-A985-D799-721A0F2A27F3}
    )

    REM Windows SDK 8.1
    REG QUERY "!SDKPRODUCTKEY!" /v "!WIN81SDKKEY!" >nul 2>nul
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "!SDKROOTKEY!" /v KitsRoot81') DO (
        REM The Installed Products key still exists even if the SDK is uninstalled.
        REM Verify that the Windows.h header exists to confirm that the SDK is installed.
        IF EXIST "%%B\Include\um\Windows.h" (
          SET SDKDIR=%%B
        )
      )

      REM Bail if no Windows SDK is found.
      IF NOT DEFINED SDKDIR (
        SET ERROR=No Windows SDK found. Exiting.
        GOTO _QUIT
      )

      SET SDKVER=8
      SET SDKMINORVER=1
    )
  )

  REM Prepend MSVC paths.
  IF "%MOZ_MSVCBITS%" == "32" (
    REM Prefer cross-compiling 32-bit builds using the 64-bit toolchain if able to do so.
    IF "%WIN64%" == "1" IF EXIST "!VCDIR!\bin\amd64_x86\vcvarsamd64_x86.bat" (
      CALL "!VCDIR!\bin\amd64_x86\vcvarsamd64_x86.bat"
      SET TOOLCHAIN=64-bit cross-compile
    )

    REM LIB will be defined if vcvarsamd64_x86.bat has already run.
    REM Fall back to vcvars32.bat if it hasn't.
    IF NOT DEFINED LIB (
      IF EXIST "!VCDIR!\bin\vcvars32.bat" (
        CALL "!VCDIR!\bin\vcvars32.bat"
        SET TOOLCHAIN=32-bit
      )
    )
  ) ELSE IF "%MOZ_MSVCBITS%" == "64" (
      IF EXIST "!VCDIR!\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat" (
        CALL "!VCDIR!\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
        SET TOOLCHAIN=64-bit
      )
  )

  REM LIB will be defined if a vcvars script has run. Bail if it isn't.
  IF NOT DEFINED LIB (
    SET ERROR=Unable to call a suitable vcvars script. Exiting.
    GOTO _QUIT
  )
)

cd "%USERPROFILE%"
IF "%USE_MINTTY%" == "1" (
  START %MOZILLABUILD%msys\bin\mintty -e %MOZILLABUILD%msys\bin\console %MOZILLABUILD%msys\bin\bash --login
) ELSE (
  %MOZILLABUILD%msys\bin\bash --login -i
)
EXIT /B

:_QUIT
ECHO MozillaBuild Install Directory: %MOZILLABUILD%
IF DEFINED VCDIR (ECHO Visual C++ %MOZ_MSVCYEAR% Directory: !VCDIR!)
IF DEFINED SDKDIR (ECHO Windows SDK Directory: !SDKDIR!)
IF DEFINED TOOLCHAIN (ECHO Trying to use the MSVC %MOZ_MSVCYEAR% !TOOLCHAIN! toolchain.)
ECHO.
ECHO %ERROR%
ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT /B
```

Comment: Which version do you need?  They are all on Microsoft's website.

Comment: @Ramhound I downloaded VS Community 2015. Is that not, or should that not contain the "Windows SDK"?

Comment: Likely No; but that wasn't my question...what version does the build script expect

Comment: @Ramhound Apparently Windows SDK 8.1

Comment: [Download it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) VS2015 would not install the 8.1 SDK but [Win 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-developer-tools)

Comment: @Ramhound after downloading and installing I get a new error: `Unable to call a suitable vcvars script. Exiting.`

Comment: sounds like the script is expecting an earlier version of VC++

Answer (score 1):

About the second problem, Feugy's answer is incorrect. There is a `vcvars` script in Visual Studio Community 2015. C++ tools are just not installed with the default settings! Make sure you tick them during installation. If you didn't you can always go to `add or remove programs > visual studio 2015 > modify`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just install VS 2013 (12.0) Update 3 or later. I had the same problem, I installed VS 2015 because I had VS 2013 Update 1 and VS 2015 doesn't seem to have the vcvars.bat script.

Strange that mozilla-build script for VS 2015 still needs this...

Once you have installed VS 2013, you can just go in its folder \VC\bin and copy vcvars32.bat to VS 2015 folder \VC\bin. It worked for me (compiling Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

On my VS 2015 (community edition), there is no `vcvars32.bat`, but there is a `vsvars32.bat`, located into`\Common7\Tools` folder.

I've patched the `mozilla-build\start-shell.bat` from (line 107):

```
  IF EXIST "!VCDIR!\bin\vcvars32.bat" (
    CALL "!VCDIR!\bin\vcvars32.bat"
    SET TOOLCHAIN=32-bit
  )
```

to:

```
  IF EXIST "!VCDIR!\..\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" (
    CALL "!VCDIR!\..\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
    SET TOOLCHAIN=32-bit
  )
```